# Stop Facebook from showing my current location when I make a post

Tags: facebook, privacy, geolocation, location

Within Facebook, any time I make a post it gives away my location as "Near The Closest Large City" (naming the city). I do not want this much detail posted about my location.

How do I stop this from happening? I have looked into the privacy and un-checked "Current Location" yet this continues.

What setting and where is it do I need to check or un-check?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

BEFORE you post the status - that detail was left off the last answer. I think that will do the trick. If not, I'll correct this post.

Click on the little "x" next to the city name to remove the location tag and it won't be added next time you update till you specially add the location yourself.

[image: remove location]

After logout/login, the setting persists

[image: no more location]

Comment: Thanks, but where exactly is the X that you refer to? I do not see it or am missing it.

Comment: @Lynda updated.